# Are there any reasons to have an abstract class with every method in the class defined?

Tags: java, inheritance

It seems that an abstract class means the definition of the class is not complete and hence cannot be instantiated.

And I saw some simple Java code which has an abstract class with all of the methods defined. Then I was wondering, why do they make it as an abstract class instead of a real class? Are they doing this so we cannot instantiate from this abstract class? Or they are getting other benefits from making an abstract class with everything defined?

Comment: Was the class declared as implementing any interfaces? Were those methods implemented?

Comment: Aside from the other answers, there's really no reason to forbid it.

Comment: FWIW, C++ doesn't *have* an "abstract" keyword, and defines a class as abstract if one or more of its functions is pure virtual, i.e. declared as `virtual void foo() = 0;`. Thus, the situation you describe cannot even happen in C++. (Not an answer, of course, I just found it an interesting fact to point out.)

Comment: How is this not a duplicate more than 6 years after Stack Overflow launched?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is possible that even though all the methods had a default implementations, these implementations weren't actually *meaningful* in the context of the application. The methods might only do internal bookkeeping while the actually useful implementation must be provided by a derived class which does what it needs to do and then calls the superclass method.

However, this is just speculation. You would have to show an actual example to tell what could be the reason for this design.

As an example, let's take a simple game engine. I have lot's of different `GameObject`s in my game.

- Some are visible, so my basic class gets a `draw()` method. But there might be invisible objects like trigger areas which don't show up at all, so I implement it as a no-op in the base class.
- Some do something when they collide with something, so each one gets a `collide(other)` method. But some don't do anything when they collide like a purely visual particle effect, so I also provide a no-op in the base class.
- Some do something every game tick, so they get a `update()` method. But some objects, like a wall, might not do anything at all on their own. So I also provide a no-op for this.

So what do I do when I have an object which is invisible, doesn't do anything on its own and doesn't interact with anything? There is no reason to have this in the game. So I make this basic class `abstract`. *Theoretically* you could instance it because all methods have an implementation, but *practically* you have no reason to ever do this, and when you try, you misunderstood how my game engine works.

Comment: Additionally, it might be that even though meaningful, the implementations were *simplistic* and would need extension in order, for instance, to  be scalable or to be restful. That would also explain why an otherwise complete class was tagged as *abstract* - to entice sub-classers to look more closely at the implementation details.

Comment: Also, providing a trivial or no-op implementation for each virtual method in the base class means a derived class only has to implement a subset of those methods to be instantiable.  Which is totally a word.

Comment: A further point is that even in cases where it would be helpful to define such no-op objects (for use as things like teleport destinations), instantiating such an object as the base type wouldn't offer any advantage versus having a sealed `MarkerObject` type which simply derives from the base `GameObject` type.  Code which needs a marker object and doesn't care if it might move or disappear could accept a `GameObject` reference, while code which needs an immutable object could require a `MarkerObject` reference.  Using type `GameObject` for marker instances would forfeit that flexibility.

Comment: Incidentally, an interesting trait of the Common Object Model is that instance types and reference types effectively inhabit separate universes.  Semantically, each class definition defines both an abstract class and a sealed class which derives directly from it; all references are of the abstract type, and all instances are of the sealed type.  While COM is very limited in many ways, having separate universes for instance types and reference types is IMHO a nice concept.

Comment: Examples from the Java API for such classes: `KeyAdapter`, `MouseAdapter`, `MouseMotionAdapter`. Other examples: `junit.framework.TestCase`.

Answer (score 22):

One typical use case is the creation of an *adapter class*. Think of a callback interface where you could be notified of 10 different events but are normally only interested in some of them. With an adapter class, you can provide empty implementations such that an actual callback only needs to implement those methods that are of interest after extending the adapter. By making the adapter abstract, you express the fact that it makes no sense to instantiate the adapter itself as it does nothing useful.

Since Java 8, you would not longer implement such an adapter but use *default methods* for the interface.

Comment: And an example from the Java API is the [KeyAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) class, which is an abstract class that implements every method from the KeyListener interface. This allows you to extend KeyAdapter and only override the method you want to implement instead of implementing KeyListener and implementing a bunch of empty methods.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there is. Sometimes you know you're creating an abstract class - one that will have to be derived from to make any actual sense, but you want to provide a default implementation to all the methods. This doesn't happen a lot, but it does happen.

UPDATE:
I just had a case like this. I'm recording various user generated events. Each event has a TimeSpan and a Description, and they all have other things as well. I've created a base event class:

```
public abstract class BaseEvent
{
    public TimeSpan EventTime {get; private set;}
    public string Description {get; protected set;}

    public BaseEvent(TimeSpan time, string desc) ...
}
```

Granted, this is C# and not Java, but had I written this in Java, I would have done exactly the same thing)

Comment: This pattern is some times called an "adapter".

Answer (score 7):

You can have an abstract class that implements several interfaces. You need not implement these methods in an abstract class, but you do need to implement them in a subclass of your abstract class.

E.g.

```
public interface MyInterface{
    void hello();
}

public abstract class Clazzy implements MyInterface {
//I need not have the interface method.
}

public class MySubclass extends Clazzy {

    @Override
    public void hello() {
        // I need to be here
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I use abstract classes as adapters, to consolidate many interfaces and give the methods default behaviour, like java.awt.event.MouseAdapter, that implements these interfaces: MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener, EventListener. Without adapter the one should count all of them in implementation and provide an empty methods. Moreover when you add some method to one of the interfaces you have to make corresponding changes in all implemented classes. But with adapter it needs only one change in adapter class.

Answer (score 4):

If a Java class is declared abstract yet has all of its methods declared, then they are doing it so it cannot be instantiated, though it may be subclassed.

"Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed."
See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 4):

You might have some classes that don't make sense in the context of your application but they do in the design. 
A silly example:
Abstract class animal, implement born and die. You don't want an "animal". You want a Dog.
This way you don't have to repeat the code each class you add. Now you can have Dog, Cat or whatever you want, this would be a good reason, anyway it's hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

I see this question is already marked answered, but I'd like to provide another alternative explanation.

Another reason for this kind of code would be to provide a base implementation for all derived classes of that abstract class.

Then when implementing new derived classes you have a runable implementation that you can then choose to override the methods of in order to customize behavior for that derived instance.

Take the case of an `BaseItemBuilder` which is abstract and provides data access logic based on a common argument, such as ItemNumber.

(Sorry for the C# code but this question is pretty much just programming theory more than it's about a specific language)

```
public abstract class BaseItemBuilder { /*I don't want anyone using this directly but I do want the base specification*/
    public virtual void GetInfoAboutItem(int itemNumber){ 
        var infoModel = _infoDataService.GetItemInfo(itemNumber);
        //project values on to internal representation of item
    }
    public virtual void GetMoreInfoAboutItem(int itemNumber){ 
        var infoModel = _infoDataService.GetMoreItemInfo(itemNumber);
        //project values on to internal representation of item
    }
    public virtual void GetEvenMoreInfoAboutItem(int itemNumber){ 
        var infoModel = _infoDataService.GetEvenMoreItemInfo(itemNumber);
        //project values on to internal representation of item
    }
    public virtual void GetYetMoreInfoAboutItem(int itemNumber){ 
        var infoModel = _infoDataService.GetYetMoreItemInfo(itemNumber);
        //project values on to internal representation of item
    }
}
```

You could then derive a `NormalItemBuilder` which uses the base implementation. This accounts for 80% of the items that you are tracking.

```
public class BaseItemBuilder { 
    /*I use the base implementation!*/
}
```

Then you derive a `SpecialType1ItemBuilder` that goes to a couple of different data services to acquire information about that particular item type, but still uses some of the base implementation defaults. This covers the next 10%.

```
public class SpecialType1ItemBuilder { /*I don't want anyone using this directly but I do want the base specification*/
    public override void GetInfoAboutItem(int itemNumber){ 
        var infoModel = _infoDataService.GetType1ItemInfo(itemNumber);
        //project values on to internal representation of item
    }

    public override void GetYetMoreInfoAboutItem(int itemNumber){ 
        var infoModel = _infoDataService.GetYetMoreType1ItemInfo(itemNumber);
        //project values on to internal representation of item
    }
}
```

Then you derive a `SpecialType2ItemBuilder' that goes to yet another set of sporadic dataservices to complete a picture of that item. This one goes overrides another set of methods that are different from Type2ItemBuilder. This covers your last 10%.

```
public class SpecialType2ItemBuilder { /*I don't want anyone using this directly but I do want the base specification*/
    public override void GetInfoAboutItem(int itemNumber){ 
        var infoModel = _infoDataService.GetType2ItemInfo(itemNumber);
        //project values on to internal representation of item
    }
    public override void GetMoreInfoAboutItem(int itemNumber){ 
        var infoModel = _infoDataService.GetMoreType2ItemInfo(itemNumber);
        //project values on to internal representation of item
    }
}
```