# Why abstract class allows to define a concrete method inside it

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract class A,which allows some abstract method and also concrete method.My question is that why abstract class allows concrete method to be declared  ,because we are using abstract class as a superclass and use the structure in the extended classes.Can anyone help me with this?

```
abstract class A{

public void aMethod(){
  System.out.println("Inside method");
 }
}
```

Comment: Just because *part of* the class is abstract, doesn't mean the entire class is. A class that's entirely abstract is the same as an interface.

Comment: Why wouldn't it ? What do you think is the goal of an abstract class ? (I'm not doing irony, just trying to better answer your question).

Comment: @Andreas I partially disagree, specially since java 8 where interface allow default methods.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I was making them equivalent in the logical concept. Yes, a class prevent multi-inheritance. Yes, an interface (now) has "default" methods (which should *not* be used as a replacement for multi-inheritance).

Comment: Because there is not such a rule that you can't declare a concrete method inside an abstract class, However if you even have one abstract method in a class the whole class should be an Abstract class.

Comment: So that its subclasses can share their default implementation unless they actually need to override them.
You can actually look at the examples of AbstractSet and its subclasses

Comment: I don't think this a duplicate of that question.  This question ask why the language allows you to define concrete methods in an abstract class ... at all.  The other is asking if it makes sense to define an abstract class where ALL of the methods are concrete.  Significantly different questions.  For a start, one is about the Java language as a language and the other is about sensible practices for using it.  (Please upvote this comment if you agree.  If lots of people agree, I'll vote to reopen.)

Comment: I see sufficient support.  Reopening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any reasons to have an abstract class with every method in the class defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27556863/1768232)

Answer (score 3):

An abstract class is there to let you share *implementation*, in addition to sharing an *interface*. An abstract class with only abstract methods would be pretty much like an interface, except it would let you share data members. This is not as powerful as letting you share *some* implementation.

Consider, for example, the [*Template Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern, which relies on the ability of abstract classes to share implementation. The template method performs the operation in a way that is common to all subclasses, letting subclasses supply the specifics.

Here is a very simple class hierarchy that illustrates this point:

```
abstract class AbstractCreature {
    protected abstract String myName();
    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + myName());
    }
    public void sayBye() {
        System.out.println("Good bye, " + myName());
    }
}
class Dolphin extends AbstractCreature {
    @Override
    protected String myName() {
        return "dolphin";
    }
}
class Bunny extends AbstractCreature {
    @Override
    protected String myName() {
        return "bunny";
    }
}
class Unicorn extends AbstractCreature {
    @Override
    protected String myName() {
        return "unicorn";
    }
}
```

This setup lets dolphins, bunnies, and unicorns to share the functionality inherited from the abstract class (i.e. the ability to say hello and goodbye). The functionality, in turn, relies on an override of the abstract method supplied in the subclass.

> if an abstract class allows concrete method, then what is the difference from a normal class?

That's a fair question. The difference is that marking a class abstract tells programmers who use it that the class must be inherited in order to be useful; a regular class, on the other hand, is expected to be useful right out of the box, without inheritance.

Comment: I cauld not get you properly,if an abstract class allows concrete method then what is the difference with normal class??

Comment: @lucifer it also allows abstract methods

Comment: @durron597 - This assumes that the question was >>correctly<< closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @durron597 This is not exactly a duplicate, although the confusion goes along the same lines in both questions. When I see that the question is about a genuine misunderstanding that does not match some other question I could remember seeing, it's faster to type up an answer, and let OP ask follow-up questions if something is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract class are not pure interfaces.
You can think of an Abstract class as mix between concrete classes and interfaces.  They allow you to provide common behaviour for all sub classes of the abstract class.

For example a door will always open the same way, you operate the handle and push.  So you could define an abstract class for door:

```
    Abstract class Door {
        public abstract void operateHandle();
        public abstract void push();

        public open() {
          operateHandle();
          push();
        }       
    }
```

This allows you to define how the handle for the door will operate in sub classes but define how the general case for a door operates.